# Select array from checkbox value with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a checkbox set to `checked`:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="24hrs" name="timeformat[]" id="isCheckedFormat" checked>

<select class="form-control" name="Mon1" id="mon1"></select>
```

I try to do a JQuery so that if it's checked it uses an array with certain values and if it's not checked than with different array values.

```
if ($('#isCheckedFormat').is(':checked')true){ 
    var vals = [1,2,3,4,5];           
}else{
     var vals = ['a','b','c','d','e'];    
 }
```

These then populate select fields:

```
for(var i = 0; i<vals.length; i++) {
$('#mon1').append('<option val="'+vals[i]+'">'+vals[i]+'</option>'); 
}
```

At the moment the 'select option' doesn't get populated by either values from the array `vals`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52jw5Lpv/5/)

Comment: Other than the typo which @Milind mentioned - you say "These then populate select fields" - where are you doing this? Seems that you've closed the change function.

Comment: I've updated this and the `select` is in the html code

Comment: so you still have the problem after fixing the typo?

Comment: Yes they are still not being populates as in the jsfiddle

Comment: See the edit in my answer - updated your fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful with the scope of your `vals` array.
see: http://jsfiddle.net/52jw5Lpv/7/

You are having a problem since you are defining the array inside the if statement, which means it doesn't exist outside it. See my link for a fix. Note that the array/var has been defined *before* the if statement.

Also - note that on the initial load, the values aren't currently reflected - so you'll need to sort that.
Also - Multiple check/uncheck will continually append the values, so that needs fixed aswell.
(Guess these are separate issues which you should be able to sort)

Comment: thanks. I've updated the JSFiddle for the other fixes to. http://jsfiddle.net/52jw5Lpv/24/

Comment: No problem. Nice one!

Answer (score 3):

You have a type in if statement. use:

```
if($('#isCheckedFormat').is(':checked'))
```